# Combining multiple rows using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Below table displays package transferred from origin to destination.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Explanation:

1. Sent America `2022-11-23 18:30:00.000` Reached China `2022-11-24 05:00:00`
2. Sent China `2022-11-24 08:18:00.000` Reached Argentina `2022-11-24 18:18:00.000`
3. Sent Argentina `2022-11-25 18:30:00.000` and reached Saudi Arabia `2022-11-25 20:30:00.000`

Comment: Why do you need double number for seqNo? I'd use a regular integers; 1, 2, 3 etc.

Comment: Hint: _self join_.

Comment: @jarlh Primary focus is on the ContryFrom , CountryTo and Remarks. . SeqNo with intergers 1,2,3,4,5 is also okay.

Comment: @jarlh I am trying using self join but since I'm not at all good in queries so facing issues. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Self join is not anough as you need one self join for every node on a multi-path route.
What you are looking for is a recursive query. See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query

Comment: @StefanWinkler Thank you for the hint but it seems my brain is spinning around looking the recursive query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope the below answer is suitable for you.

**less than <**

```
select  f.id,f.Country CountryFrom, t.Country CountryTo
, convert(varchar(4),f.seqNo) + '-' + convert(varchar(4),t.seqNo) seqNo
, f.Send, t.Arrive,concat('Send ', f.Country ,' ', f.Send,' Reached ', t.Country,' ',t.Arrive) Remarks from IPhone f inner join IPhone t on f.seqNo < t.seqNo order by id;
```

Thanking you

Comment: Beautifully done. . Thank you so much Sirji. Apka bahut bahut dhanyawad.

Comment: Note that this will work if you don't need the remarks part, because all information is available in the self join. If you need the "via" information from the Remarks column shown in the question, you need a recursive query.

Comment: Yes, but the requirement is to populate the remarks only if there is VIA otherwise keep it blank. I think I need to use the recursive anyway.

Comment: @StefanWinkler Can you please help me in the recursive section please.